# C++ Getting all posiible Children from Tic-Tac-Toe Tree using Vectors

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, while-loop

Have to write a implementation where given a tic-tac-toe "board" of size n it returns all of the children of the given board. However, it is not printing out any of the values inside each vector, and I'm not sure why.

Here we are assuming X (denoted as a 1) always goes before O (denoted as a -1). Empty spaces are denotes as 0.

Here is is the implementation file, where the header file has `vector<int> b_;` and `int n_;`   as its private data members:

```
#include "tttboard.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

tttboard::tttboard()
{
}

tttboard::tttboard(int n, vector<int> &e)
{
    n_ = n;
    for (int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
    {
        e.push_back(i);
    }
}

tttboard::tttboard(int n){
    n_ = n;
    for (int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
        b_.push_back(0);
}

vector<tttboard> tttboard::possibleNextBoards(int turn) const{
    vector<tttboard> children;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
    {
        children.push_back(temp);
    }
    return children;
}

bool tttboard::operator==(const tttboard& rhs) const
{
    bool check = true;
    for (int i=0; i < b_.size(); i++)
    {
        if (b_[i] == rhs.b_[i])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return check;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream & output, const tttboard &board)
{
    output << "{";
    for (int i=0; i < board.b_.size(); i++)
    {
        output << board.b_[i];
        if (i != board.b_.size() - 1)
            output << ", ";
    }
    output << "}";
    return output;
}
```

**EDIT**: This is the main file that I am working with (apologies if it's a bit long)

```
#include "tttboard.h"
#include "gTree.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void Tokenize(string line, vector<string> & tokens, string delimiters = "\t "){
string token = "";
    string OneCharString = " ";
    for (int i=0; i<line.size(); i++)
            if (find(delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end(), line[i])!=delimiters.end()) // line[i] is one of the delimiter characters
            {
                    if (token != "")
                            tokens.push_back(token);
                    token = "";
            }
            else
            {
                    OneCharString[0] = line[i];
                    token +=OneCharString;
            }

    if (token != "")
            tokens.push_back(token);
}

int getTurn(vector<int> b){
    int s = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
        s+=b[i];
    if (s==0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (argc!=3){
        cout << "usage: executable.o n board\n example of board:(\"{0,0,1,0,0,-1,1,0,0}\")";
        return 1;
    }

int n= atoi(argv[1]);
string str_board = argv[2];
vector<string> tokens;
Tokenize(str_board,tokens," {,}");
vector<int> board;
for (int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++){
    board.push_back(atoi(tokens[i].c_str()));
}
if (n*n!= board.size()){
    cout<< "n and board are not consistent!\n";
    return 1;
}

    tttboard p(n,board);
int turn = getTurn(board);
vector<tttboard> v = p.possibleNextBoards(turn);    

cout <<"children of the given board:" << endl;
for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i] << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What does `main` look like? Also, `tttboard::operator==` doesn't need to be that complicated: just a `for(...) { if(b_[i] != rhs.b_[i]) return false; } return true;` will do, and the logic in `possibleNextBoards` doesn't make much sense to me. Neither of those are related to your problem, though.

Comment: @HTNW edited with the main file above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::cout is buffered. If you add an std::endl does the output get printed? Try adding  std::flush after the cout line, eg cout << .. << std::flush;

Comment: still printing out empty stuff

Comment: Does this line get printed?  cout << "usage: executable.o n board\n example of board:(\"{0,0,1,0,0,-1,1,0,0}\")" - without a newline?

Comment: that does print out, i've edited my code to reflect some changes